# C# ItextSharp not showing Arabic

Tags: c#, itext

i try to add Arabic but not showing right

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Test_PDf
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SaveFileDialog Sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "PDF file|*.pdf", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if(Sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                    PdfWriter  writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create));
                    doc.Open();
                    writer.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
                    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                    var phrase = new Phrase(Txt_1.Text, new Font(bf, 12));                    
                    doc.Add(phrase);
                    doc.Close();         
                }
            }          
        }
    }
}
```

every letter not connect with  each other letter it show Arabic but not right away i try many away but no one work every time give me letter alone not connect

Comment: for propper Arabic support with iText, you should use pdfCalligraph ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.pdfcalligraph), [product page](https://itextpdf.com/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph)).

Answer (score 0):

this code this code to save arabic text as pdf with right away
write at RichBoxTxt and save it as pdf where u want at your computer

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a font for Arabic script
            BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            Font arabicFont = new Font(baseFont, 12);

            using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                dialog.Filter = "PDF Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
                dialog.DefaultExt = "pdf";
                dialog.AddExtension = true;

                if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Document document = new Document();
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(dialog.FileName, FileMode.Create));
                    document.Open();

                    // Specify right-to-left text direction
                    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
                    ct.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;

                    // Add Arabic text to PDF
                    ct.AddText(new Phrase(Txt_1.Text, arabicFont));
                    ct.SetSimpleColumn(0, 0, 595, 842); // Set the column dimensions
                    ct.Go();

                    document.Close();

                    MessageBox.Show("PDF file saved successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
```

i hope it help